# How to access the data points within a cluster?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

So I am trying to create a Google Maps like software that would evaluate the trip time from point a to point b based on the taxi data.

```
 val taxiFile = sc.textFile("/resources/LabData/nyctaxisub.csv")
    val header = taxiFile.first()
    val taxiNoHead = taxiFile.filter(x=> (x !=header))

    //3, 4, 9, 10 are the dropoff and pickup longitude and latitude 
    val taxiData=taxiNoHead.
        filter(_.split(",")(3)!="" ).  
        filter(_.split(",")(4)!="") 

    val taxiFence=taxiData.
        filter(_.split(",")(3).toDouble>40.70).
        filter(_.split(",")(3).toDouble<40.77).
        filter(_.split(",")(4).toDouble>(-74.02)).
        filter(_.split(",")(4).toDouble<(-73.7)).
        filter(_.split(",")(9).toDouble>40.70).
        filter(_.split(",")(9).toDouble<40.77).
        filter(_.split(",")(10).toDouble>(-74.02)).
        filter(_.split(",")(10).toDouble<(-73.7))

    val taxi=taxiFence.
        map{
            line=>Vectors.dense(
                line.split(',').slice(3,5).map(_ .toDouble)
            )
        }.cache()

    val iterationCount=10
    val clusterCount=40

    val model=KMeans.train(taxi,clusterCount,iterationCount)
    val clusterCenters=model.clusterCenters.map(_.toArray)

    clusterCenters.foreach(lines=>println(lines(0),lines(1)))
```

(Here is a link to map with all of my cluster centers http://www.darrinward.com/lat-long/?id=1922446)

Now my problem is that I am not sure how to calculate the average time from one cluster to another. This could be done easily if there was a way to access the data points assigned to each cluster and then take an average of the trip_time_in_secs for trips that go from the cluster to the other cluster nearest to the dropoff point. In addition if there were clusters between points a and b, for instance point c. It would also calculate the avg. time from point a to c and from c to b and then sum these together. Similarly to Dijkstra's algorithm.

Is this possible to do? And if yes, how?

Comment: Have you looked into Spark GraphX - it offers a bunch of graph algorithms.

Comment: Not yet, but I will look into that. Thanks!